# IQueryable() to ListAsync() conversion issue due to filter on list inside a list

Tags: linq, async-await

I have an issue with filtering a list inside a list on a async method.

```
private async Task<List<UserList>> GetAsyncList(string query)
{

     var result = GetUserList.Where(x =>

           x.FirstName.ToUpper().Contains(query.ToUpper())                                                                               
           || x.LastName.ToUpper().Contains(query.ToUpper())                                                                            
           || x.EmailId.ToUpper().Contains(query.ToUpper())                    
           **|| x.UserRole.Any(a => a.ToUpper().Contains(query.ToUpper()))**);

           return await result.ToListAsync(); }
```

Getting the below exception

> Expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable`1[System.String]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String]' of method 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] ToList[String](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String])'
>   Parameter name: arg0

Kindly help me with this!

Comment: Can you post the complete stack trace of that exception?

Comment: Is `x.UserRole` a string or an IEnumerable?